# On the proof of Fleury's algorithm. (Question 2)

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

On pages 42-43 in [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wROJ7.jpg)], it says:

> We conclude our introduction to Eulerian graphs with an algorithm for
>   constructing an Eulerian trail in a give Eulerian graph. The method is
>   know as **Fleury's algorithm**.
>
> **THEOREM 2.12** Let $G$ be an Eulerian graph. Then the following construction is always possible, and produces an Eulerian trail of
>   $G$.
>
> Start at any vertex $u$ and traverse the edges in an arbitrary manner,
>   subject only to the following rules:
>
> (i) erase the edges as they are traversed, and if any isolated
>   vertices result, erase them too;
>
> (ii) at each stage, use a bridge only if there is no alternative.
>
> ***Proof.*** We show first that the construction can be carried out at each stage.
>
> Suppose that we have just reached a vertex $v$, erasing the edges as
>   we go. If $v \neq u$, then the subgraph $H$ that remains is connected
>   and has only two vertices of odd degrees, $u$ and $v$. To show that the construction can be carried out, we must show that the removal of the next edge does not disconnect $H$ $-$ or, equivalently, that $v$ is incident with at most one bridge. But if this is not the case, then there exists a bridge $vw$ such that the component $K$ of $H-vw$ containing $w$ does not contain $u$ (see the figure below). Since the vertex $w$ has odd degree in $K$, ...
>   [image]

Please look at the last sentence of the proof. Why does the vertex $w$ have odd degree in $K$? Thanks in advance.

[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wROJ7.jpg)] Robin J. Wilson, Introduction to Graph Theory, 5th ed., Prentice Hall, 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the vertex $w$ has even degree in $H$. This is because it had even degree in $G$, and if we have visited it $k$ times so far, we have used up $2k$ of its edges (we arrived at $w$ $k$ times, and left it $k$ times), so an even number remain. Removing the edge $vw$ leaves it with odd degree, and all the edges from $w$ apart from $vw$ lie in $K$, so it has odd degree in $K$.

Answer (score 1):

In the graph $G$, the only vertices with odd degree are $u$ and $v$.
Therefore $w$ has even degree in $G$ and so it has odd degree in $K$
(since it is no longer adjacent to $v$ in $K$).